# Reason behind in post deletion by moderator

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have a quick question from the moderator.

May I know the reason, why this question gets deleted.
- Is it an invalid question
- Is it breaks any protocol
- Or any other specific reason

[Google map sometimes not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692302/google-map-sometimes-not-loading)

Comment: Your post was deleted because it was over 30 days old and had a negative score. Refer to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/202316

Comment: I suggest to vote for to migration to Meta.

Comment: Really  I did not find any flaws with that question for which people marked it with negative.

Comment: @RajuMahato I haven't seen your post, but from the title I am guessing, you didn't provide enough information to diagnose the problem :( After that it was just standard cleaning script as linked.

Comment: Your post is now un-deleted, good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Community auto-deletes unanswered questions with a negative score, after 30 days.

See [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006):

> [...]  the Community user will delete questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

The process is entirely automated and not a judgement call on your question; it was the *down vote* that judged it, and a complete lack of upvotes in all that time.

Note that your question had also received a off-topic close vote before it was auto-deleted.

The question was perhaps not all that bad; I cleaned up the formatting a little and improved the grammar. If you updated it with the feedback from the comments, you probably request to have it undeleted, or we could try to undelete it for you.

If you ask a moderator to undelete it, feel free to point to this post in your 'other' flag message.

Comment: "Because it was deleted by a moderator (the Community User has moderator status), the community cannot undelete it." Are you sure? It has an undelete button and clicking it asks me if I want to cast an undelete vote.

Comment: @Powerlord: this changed [quite recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167500/should-questions-removed-automatically-for-inactivity-really-be-non-undeletable) and I wasn't aware of the change; we can indeed now undelete the post.